# Jasmine: Testing variable state before function is called

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, sinon

I am invoking a function that depends on the global window object having several variables defined before it can run successfully by injecting a 3rd party script. ie.

```
window.foo = 1;
function calledAfter() {
    // inject 3rd party script that depends on
    // window.foo !== undefined
}
```

Using Jasmine and Sinon.js, how would I test to ensure `window.foo` is set before `calledAfter` is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't. This is exactly one of the reasons why storing state globally is a VERY bad idea.
If the function depends on a specific configuration-set it should be injected with the set or - less preferably - have a way to request that set.
And in general, dependency management isn't unit tested, that's what integration testing is for.